# Help identify this Mech movie

Tags: identify-this-movie

Saw it in a bar in California, in or around 2009.

It looked like it was shot similarly to "Sky Captain and the World of Tomorrow", i.e. live action actors on a green-screen and CGI background.

The color palette very heavy on the red, overall a grainy look.

Large Mechs in a war-type scenario, airships, lots of missiles at the end.

The story seemed anti-capitalist, but it was not in English, and there were no subtitles.

Seemed like it may have been Chinese, Japanese, or Russian...though I am not sure.

Comment: Is there more information you can remember about the mechs, such as their size, whether they could fly or if they had one or many people inside?

Comment: @CrowTRobot, with the help of an anon, just found it -- Casshern: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405821/?ref_=nv_sr_1
Ever seen it?

Comment: No, but congratulations, you should add an answer with the name and maybe a brief summary of the film so others can find it easily in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie is called Casshern.
http://imdb.com/title/tt0405821/?ref_=nv_sr_1

From Wikipedia: "Tetsuya Azuma (東鉄也 Azuma Tetsuya?), also known as Casshern, is an android with a human consciousness aka a neoroider (人造人間 Jinzō Ningen?, lit. "artificial human"). Tetsuya turned himself into an android for the purpose of hunting down and destroying robots that have taken over the world."

Comment: coming from the anime Casshan: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casshan